# Why does .alert() show only the same values permanently?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to implement a code which shows the coordinate of a pressed area with an `.alert()` function. Here's the jQuery code that I got:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#plot").bind("click", function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.offsetLeft + ", " + event.target.offsetTop);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:pink" id="plot"></div>
```

"Plot" is an ID of a Canvas area.
Every time I press on the area, `.alert()` pops-up with the same values. What does it mean in my program and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all those who need a coordinate of a clicked point *inside* the area: I do not recommend using `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` (or `offset().top` and `offset().left`). Instead of them, it is better to use `offsetX` and `offsetY` which make it possible to find a relative coordinate:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#plot").bind("click", function(event){
                alert(event.offsetX + ", " + event.offsetY);
            })
        });
```

I really hope that this additional answer will be useful for all those who is looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

`event.target.offsetLeft` and `event.target.offsetTop` are the coordinates of the element that the click occured in. Since it doesn't move, the values don't change.

What you need are the `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` variables:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#plot").bind("click", function(event) {
    console.log(event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background:pink" id="plot"></div>
```

More info on MDN

[on `event.clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX)

[on `event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is still a problem with it: I can get a position on a page by using `clientX` and `clientY`, but not on a canvas element.